# Use JWT Token to access get api (POSTMAN)

Tags: symfony, jwt, postman

I'm using `FosUserBundle` and `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle`.

On login, it successfully generates tokens but when I'm trying to use to get data from `/api/users`, I'm getting following response:

```
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}.
```

I'm adding the token to the request's header (via postman).

```
Authorization: Bearer myToken
```

I don't understand the problem as I'm using the right token.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Apache2** try to add

```
 SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

to your `.htaccess` file.